# How to clone more than one private repository on CPanel

Tags: laravel, git, github, ssh, cpanel

I am having some issues cloning a private repo into my CPanel server, because of a previously cloned private GitHub repository. I have cloned it before using ssh access and everything went right. However, I need to clone another repo that is also private and using ssh access, as well.

I followed all the procedures to copy the private repo into CPanel as the previous one. However, I'm having issues with access rights, getting the same message as following:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there a  way to clone two private repositories with different ssh keys? how to clone those repositories without getting the same message above?

Thanks in advance.

**-------------------------------------------------   EDIT-----------------------------------------------------**

My config file in the .ssh folder is the following

```
Host region_admin
  HostName <git@github.com:SthefanyRangel/regionadmin.git>
  User regioye5@cs2006.webhostbox.net:2083
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host renovafacil
  HostName <git@github.com>
  User regioye5@cs2006.webhostbox.net:2083
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.rf
  
Host regionadmin-ra2
  HostName <git@github.com>
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/region_admin
```

Where my attempts to connect to the second account are the last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation "[CPanel / How to Copy an Account with SSH Keys](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/transfers-and-restores/how-to-copy-an-account-with-ssh-keys/)", you might need a second key if the GitLab repository uses the same account than the first one.

If not, try:

```
git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -Tv' clone git@github:...
```

That will give you an idea of which keys are considered. If your second key is not with a default name, it would need a `~/.ssh/config` in order to specify it.

You can test a config entry with:

```
ssh -T region_admin
```

Note: `Hostname` is always just the hostname, not  `<git@github.com:SthefanyRangel/regionadmin.git>`

Your first `~/.ssh/config` entry should therefore be (for the actual GitHub username, for which the public SSH key has been registered):

```yaml
Host region_admin
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then:

```
cd /path/to/regionadmin
git remote set-url origin region_admin:SthefanyRangel/regionadmin.git
```

Comment: I've tried this command, however it gets aborted because of the access rights. I have the config file in .ssh folder, I don{t know how to configure it but I{ll make and edit so that you can verify

Comment: @SthefanyRangel It should display some debug output, *before* getting aborted.

Comment: I got the following: `Cloning into 'regionadmin'...
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home3/regioye5/.ssh/config
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github\303: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @SthefanyRangel Yes, that is because of the `Hostname` entry, as I mentioned in my edited answer. Keep `Hostname` to `github.com` (no git, no user/repo)

Comment: I keep getting the same using the command you wrote here. `ssh: Could not resolve hostname <github.com>: Name or service not known` .Could you please give me an example of how to define the ssh configuration for that host in the config file? I'll be very grateful

Comment: @SthefanyRangel Sure thing. I have edited the answer accordingly.